# How to pass arguments to a shell script using `make-process` function?

Tags: shell, bash

Consider a script file: *~/project/script.sh*

```sh
echo "arg 1 $1"  
echo "arg 2 $2"
echo "arg 3 $3"
```

And elisp file that invokes it using `make-process`: *~/project/special-mode/special-mode.el*

```lisp
(let* ((script-file  (shell-quote-argument (expand-file-name "~/project/script.sh")))
       (argA          (shell-quote-argument "A"))
       (argB          (shell-quote-argument "B")))
       (make-process
             :name            "special-mode"
             :buffer          "*SPECIAL-MODE*"
             :command         `( "sh" "-c" ,script-file ,argA  ,argB )
             :connection-type 'pipe
             :sentinel   nil)))
```

**Question**

The function evaluates but the arguments to the shell script (argA and argB) are never passed.
  Any idea how to fix this?

**Emacs Version**

GNU Emacs 28.0.50

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the use of `sh -c`. When using the `-c` flag, the next argument is expected to be the full command line that will be expanded by the subshell.

You can try this in a regular shell:

```sh
ditto:~% sh -c echo a b c

ditto:~% sh -c 'echo a b c'
a b c
ditto:~%
```

In the first example, `echo` is being executed correctly, but because only the first argument after `-c` is being passed to the subshell, the `a b c` arguments are lost to `echo`. In the second example, the entire command line is being passed as a single argument, and thus `echo` is seeing `a b c` in the subshell.

So naturally, you have to take this into account in your elisp by passing a *single* argument to `-c`:

```lisp
(let* ((script-file (shell-quote-argument (expand-file-name "/bin/echo")))
       (arg-a       (shell-quote-argument "A"))
       (arg-b       (shell-quote-argument "B")))
  (make-process
   :name            "special-mode"
   :buffer          "*SPECIAL-MODE*"
   :command         `("sh" "-c" ,(concat script-file " " arg-a " " arg-b))
   :connection-type 'pipe
   :sentinel   nil))
```

I would recommend, however, that instead of using `sh -c`, just call your binaries directly unless you specifically *need* to use shell interpretatiton, because it works more naturally and has more predictable outcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

As pointed out by xuchunyang, adding a shebang line to the script.sh and calling it like an ordinary executable is a much cleaner solution. That is:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "arg 1 $1"  
echo "arg 2 $2"
echo "arg 3 $3"
```

**Old Solution**

Removing the -c flag fixed the issue. The -c flag is used to call shell commands in-line(and probably more).

```
sh -c[-abCefhimnuvx][-o option][+abCefhimnuvx][+o option]command_string
               [command_name [argument...]]
```

From [The Single UNIX ® Specification, Version 2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/sh.html)

> ```
> -c        Read  commands from the command_string operand. Set the value of
>           special parameter 0 (see Special Parameters ) from the value  of
>           the  command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2,
>           and so on) in sequence from the remaining argument operands.  No
>           commands shall be read from the standard input.
> ```

Comment: You can just execute the program directly without `sh` by adding a shebang and making it executable. `sh -c 'echo $0 $1' app_name arg1` works while `sh -c 'echoargs' app_name arg1` doesn't because as you mentioned the former is a inline script, but the later the program `echoargs` will run in a new process with its own arguments.